# Как сменить цвет текста в toolbar?

Tags: android

У меня отдельный XML-файл с toolbar и как мне поменять в нем цвет текста(Label)?

Comment: `app:titleTextColor="@color/your_color"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В разметку `ToolBar` добавьте атрибут:

```
app:titleTextColor="@color/your_color"
```

Answer (score 2):

Согласно выдаче выдаче гугла на запрос

> [android toolbar title color](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20toolbar%20title%20color)

и его первой ссылке на [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26852454/3212712)

можно с недавних пор использовать атрибут `app:titleTextColor`

```
app:titleTextColor="@color/primary_text"
```

Comment: спасибо, гуглить также надо учится....